# C# If Else proper "do nothing" syntax

Tags: c#, syntax

I am fairly new to programming and in my most recent work I created the following if else statement nested within a for loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < originalColumnCells.Count; i++)
{
    if (originalColumnCells[i] == sortedColumnCells[i])
    {
        // Do Nothing
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

In the if statement, as you can see, I want the method to do nothing if the statement is true. In this case, is it proper syntax to comment out "// Do Nothing", or should I leave it as open and closed braces? Or maybe put the braces at the end of the if line?

Any suggestions on the "right" way to handle this would be appreciated

Comment: ```if (originalColumnCells[i] != sortedColumnCells[i]){/*do what you want*/}```

Comment: Reverse it. `originalColumnCells[i] != sortedColumnCells[i]`. Now you dont need else

Comment: invert the statement. `if (originalColumnCells[i] != sortedColumnCells[i]) { return false }` then you don't have to worry about a "do nothing" block

Comment: None of these - invert the condition and perform work when it matches. Or convert the loop to a LINQ query that returns only matching indexes, records, whatever and works on them

Comment: Why not try it out? You have a debugger? Then it´s easy to find out if it works.

Comment: Interestingly enough, [There's a built-in function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348567(v=vs.110).aspx) that appears to do what you want

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Why not negate the expression?

```
for (int i = 0; i < originalColumnCells.Count; i++)
{
    if (originalColumnCells[i] != sortedColumnCells[i])
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

In general, you want to explain things that are unusual.

```
{

}
```

Is this supposed to be empty? Did something get deleted? Better to make your intent explicit:

```
{
    // do nothing
}
```

But -- also in general -- you probably want to change your if statement so you don't end up with empty statements. I see several answers saying to change the comparison from `==` to `!=`. However, what about some statement like

```
if (a > b && c == d || Object.ReferenceEquals(null, e)) ...
```

In order to invert this, you would change `>` to `<=`, change `==` to `!=`, change `&&` and `||` operators, etc. I find it simplest to just invert the entire statement with `!` instead of trying to change each comparison operator:

```
if (!(a > b && c == d || Object.ReferenceEquals(null, e))) ...
```

Answer (score 6):

Change the if statement to != and remove the else all together:

```
if (originalColumnCells[i] != sortedColumnCells[i])
{
   return false;
}
// No else
```

Answer (score 3):

You can inverse the statement:

```
if (originalColumnCells[i] != sortedColumnCells[i])
```

But then something else. Sometimes you want indicate you have thought about the need of an `else` branch but you don't need one. (I sometimes want one if I have larger code blocks with complex statements) Then it is fine in my opinion to use something along these lines:

```
else
{
    // no action, already handled later on in bla bla
}
```

Comment: I would argue that if you need to state such things, then your code is too complex and not really maintainable.

Comment: Well, sometimes it is indeed, but dividing code in smaller chunks might make things worse (especially if you have to `ref` input quite some variables). I don't like it either and won't advice using it, but if you need to, it is okay.